# Odd sum subarrays approach not working for large size array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

**I was asked a coding question in a competition recently.**

> Find the total numbers of sub-arrays that can be formed from the given array of length N 
>   having an odd
>   sum of its elements,
>
> sub-arrays are not necessarily to be contiguous.
>
> Array length: 1 <= N <= 100000

```
For instance: [-4,-4,1] -> [-4, 1], [-4, 1], [-4,-4, 1], [1]



    //  So if the input is this array then our function should return the count as 
          4;
```

**My approach:**

I, separated out odd elements with even elements and kept a count of both odd elements and even elements.

**X: the total number of odd-length subsets from the odd elements set.**

**Formula used: pow(2, num_odd - 1)**

```
// derived by the pattern:
 // 1 element set : 1 odd length subset : pow(2, 1 - 1)
 // 2 element set : 2 odd length subsets: pow(2, 2 - 1)
 // 3 element set : 4 odd length subsets: pow(2, 3 - 1)....follows
```

**Y: And, the total number of subsets from the even elements set.**

**Formula used: pow(2, num_even) - 1   `//excluding empty set`**

> ***So, mapping every subset of X with Y will give me all subsets having an odd sum as each set in X has an odd sum and each set in Y has an
>   even sum so combining them will give me all odd sum subarrays.***
>
> ***And all the sets in X taken separately will also contribute in the answer as sum of odd elements the odd number of times is also odd***

So, final count becomes:

> **X * Y + X**

C++ Code:

```
int solve(vector<int> &A){

    int num_odd = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        if(A[i] % 2 != 0)
            num_odd++;
    }

    /// edge case
    if(num_odd == 0)
        return 0;

    int num_even = A.size() - num_odd;

    unsigned long long X = (unsigned long long int)pow(2, num_odd - 1) % 1000000007;
    unsigned long long Y = (unsigned long long int)(pow(2, num_even) - 1) % 1000000007;

    unsigned long long cnt_ = ( ((X * Y) % 1000000007) + X) % 1000000007;

    return cnt_;
}
```

**Now, this code was generating the correct output for small inputs but this was giving the wrong answer for inputs say length 20 or more.**

I want to know, is this approach of calculating the total odd-sum subarrays would be bad if the array size is large.

> Do you have some better way to solve this?

Comment: Note that [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is a *floating point* function, and as such could have compounding rounding errors.

Comment: `[-4,-4,-1] -> [-4, 1], [-4, 1], [-4,-4, 1], [1]` ? Where did `1` come from? I am assuming answer is `3` for this.  Also, is this for subarrays or subsequences?

Comment: The result can be much larger than any primitive C++ type can hold — more than 30,000 decimal digits, I bellieve.

Comment: @vivek_23,Sorry, the array was not [-4, -4, -1], it was [-4, -4, 1] probably a typo!

Comment: Should I think of other logic or can I fix this pow(2, x) for large numbers, which exceeds any primitive type in c++?